# How to know what child is belonging to their parent?

Tags: java, xml

I have a XML-file with over 12k tags.
All the tags have a tagId, like:

```
<first_tag>                   tagId = 1
   <second_tag_first_child>   tagId = 2
```

So on, so forth.

In addition to tagId they all need to have an parentId, so the child know what parent they belong to.

```
<root_tag>                               parentId = 0 | tagId = 1
  <first_tag>                            parentId = 1 | tagId = 2
     <second_tag_first_child>            parentId = 2 | tagId = 3
     <third_tag_second_child>            parentId = 2 | tagId = 4
        <fourth_tag_first_grandchild>    parentId = 4 | tagId = 5
  <fifth_tag>                            parentId = 1 | tagId = 6
```

Does anyone know how to make the logic so i can get the parentId?
What I need is a `System.out.println(tag + parentId + tagId + "\n")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an XML-file and you want to read it with a Java-program. You could either go through hell and write your own program to read XML-files, or you use already existing packages for that, for example the SAX-library.

To use SAX-parser use these import-statements:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
```

You have to create a SAX-parser from a SAXParserFactory. The factory itself is created with a static factory-method.

```
SAXParserFactory f = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
```

You use `parser` to read the XML-file and give the output to `DefaultHandler`. Everything is handled by `DefaultHandler` so there is where your code goes.

[Documentation of DefaultHandler](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a poor XML file. Are you sure that's really a good representation of the file.

If you use a SAX parser, one solution is to keep a stack of the objects you're parsing. You can keep a pointer to the top item in the stack, then when you encounter  you can pop the stack and point topOfStack back to the top of the stack.

Then you have to parse the characters yourself (if that's really what the file does), which involves implementing:

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException   
{
}
```

But you'll need to cache the strings that come in and then process them before you begin handling the next startElement() or endElement(). Yes, it's kind of a pain, which is one reason your XML file is a bad idea. (But maybe you don't have a choice.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

the xml-file does not look like this. whats important is that the tags have a tagId and a parentId. The parentId need to match the tagId if that is the child to the parent.