# Is there a library I can use to ignore all html tags/elements while readline?

Tags: java, html, string

e.g a string like this

```
<p>colors:</p><ul><li>RED: red</li><li>BLACK: dark</li><li>Other: other colors</li></ul><p>To view the chart as a pie chart, click <b>Pie Chart</b>.</p>
```

or

```
<i class="{0}"></i> Pie Chart
```

Say if i want to do simple shift cypher type of things, shift all alphabetical character 1 to the left but not change any of the HTML tags. 
is there a way to do that using some existing library?
I know there are some existing lib I can use to remove the tags but I don't know if there exist anything that recognize pieces of the line read in are HTML and I can decide to ignore it if I want to.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a sophisticated library that understands HTML (or XML in general), the SAX-parser is great. It is not too complicated either. The packages are `javax.xml.parsers` and `org.xml.sax`.

The SAX-parser is an event-based parser: it will read through the XML (or HTML) and call specific methods when it encounters different things. What you then do is to define these methods.

[Here is a small post about the SAX-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844045/5221346)